# Django URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. for endpoints with and without slash

Tags: python, django, url, request

I am getting this warning and I would like to get rid of it... 
My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^(?P<Model>[A-Za-z]+)',
        GenericViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'}),
    ) # aka model endpoint

]
```

What I want to achieve is a request to `/admin` and `/admin/` to fall to the admin site and any other request will be passed to my generic model handling API.

The problem is that when I set only `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`, a request to `/admin` falls to the model endpoint and when I set only `path('admin', admin.site.urls)`, a request to `/admin/` falls to the model endpoint. I get why this happens, Django goes through all endpoints before adding the slash to the end and going through them again with appended slash.

So I have to specify both `admin` and `admin/` path, to make both requests to `/admin` and `/admin/` fall to the admin site and that is  causing the warning to appear... Which probably should not be happening...

Can I go somehow around this? (Without changing my desired url paths...)

p.s. I have `APPEND_SLASH` set to True

EDIT:

When I use only

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

both requests to `/admin` and `/admin/` fall correctly to admin page.

Comment: Django, by default, redirects non slash urls to slash urls, i.e. `/admin` to `/admin/`. You don't need two urls. See [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) settings.

Comment: The problem is that when I set only path('admin/', admin.site.urls), a request to /admin falls to the model endpoint and when I set only path('admin', admin.site.urls), a request to /admin/ falls to the model endpoint. Which should not be happening... This is probably the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem now. If you only set `admin/` and don't set `admin`, this gets matched with your regular expression.

From `APPEND_SLASH` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) (emphasis mine):

> ...if the request URL **does not match** any of the patterns in the URLconf **and it doesn't end in a slash**, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended.

So, django is not redirecting `admin` to `admin/` because your regex pattern is matching with `admin` as your expression doesn't contain a slash in the end.

You should specify a slash and dollar sign in your regex pattern so that django  matches the complete url with the slash.

This should work:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

re_path(r'^(?P<Model>[A-Za-z]+)/$', ...),
```

Comment: The problem is that when I set only path('admin/', admin.site.urls), a request to /admin falls to the model endpoint and when I set only path('admin', admin.site.urls), a request to /admin/ falls to the model endpoint. I get why this happens, Django goes through all endpoints before adding the slash to the end and going through them again with appended slash.

Comment: @Charlestone Yes, I understand that. Hence I suggested you to add a slash in your regex pattern. I tested a similar scenario on my computer, and it seems to fix the issue for me.